# Avro schema: adding a new field with default value - straight default value or a union with null?

Tags: avro, backwards-compatibility

So I have an avro record like so (call it `v1`):

```
record MyRecord {
    array<string> keywords;
}
```

I'd like to add a field `caseSensitive` with a default value of `false` (call it `v2`). The first approach I have is:

```
record MyRecord {
    array<string> keywords;
    boolean caseSensitive = false;
}
```

According to [schema evolution](https://docs.confluent.io/current/avro.html#schema-evolution), this is both backward and forward compatible because a reader with the new schema `v2` reading a record that was encoded with old writer schema `v1` will be able to fill this field with the default value and a reader with older schema `v1` will be able to read a record encoded with the new writer schema `v2` because it will just ignore the newly added field.

Another way to add this field is by adding a `union` type of `null` and `boolean` with a default value of null, like so:

```
record MyRecord {
    array<string> keywords;
    union{null, boolean} caseSensitive = null;
}
```

This is also backward and forward compatible. I can see that sometimes one would want to use the 2nd approach if there is no clear default value for a field (such as `name`, `address`, etc.). But given my use case with a clear default value, I'm thinking of going with the first solution. My question is: is there any other concerns that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There will be a potential issue with writers in the first case--apparently writers do not use default values. So a writer writing "old data" (missing the new field--so writer is publishing a record with the "keywords" field only) will blow up against the first schema. Same writer using second schema will be successful, and the "caseSensitive" field will be set to null in the resulting message.

Comment: hmm, so if that is true, then as long as I can ensure that all my writers will be on new schema with the migration, then I'm good, correct?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not an expert :). I just happened to be looking at the writer issue recently, so am aware of that aspect. As far as I know, readers do use default values, so you should be good.